# GithubClient Issue Create throws NotFoundException

Tags: c#, github, octokit.net

I'm new to `Octokit.Net`.

and I want to create issue in my program...

So I coded like this.

```
var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("Hello"));

var i = new NewIssue("asdf");
i.Body = "asdf";

var issue = github.Issue.Create("JoyLeeSoft", "test", i);
```

When I call `Create`  function, function always throws `NotFoundException`.

And the error message just **"Not Found"**

But, the repository is avaiable. https://github.com/JoyLeeSoft/test

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an issue means being properly authenticated first (as in [`Tests/Authentication/BasicAuthenticatorTests.cs`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/Octokit.Tests/Authentication/BasicAuthenticatorTests.cs))

If not authenticated, the default response of GitHub can be "repository not found".

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't understand that code.. would you tell me what that code mean...?

Comment: @Lee the codes in https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/tree/master/Octokit.Tests/Authentication are example on how to authenticate, which you must do *before* trying to create an issue. Creating an issue *without* authenticating first would result in a repo  "not found" error message.